# Using cURL to POST data to a web form

Tags: curl

I'm trying to use cURL to post data to the form on this URL:

```
http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/
```

Trying curl with these values:

```
curl -d "remoteAddress=google.com&submit=Check" http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/
```

how can i correctly send the request to the server?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form at the URL you cite does not use HTTP POST, so there is no way to use curl (or any other HTTP POST tool) to get the results you expect.

The submit button on this form triggers an AJAX request to POST the variables `remoteAddress` and `key` to the URL http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/php/get-web-sites-on-web-server-json-data.php.  The JSON from this URL is then used to modify the data on the original page.

See the function `reverseIpDomainCheck` within the script file at http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/web-sites-on-web-server/js/tool.js.

You can try to use curl to POST to this URL, but my one attempt returned zero data.  The author of the site likely validates the value of `key` to prevent random individuals from using the tool directly.  You can contact the author to see what value is required for `key`.